# How do prove $12^n - 4^n - 3^n +1$ is divisible by 6 using mathematical induction, where n is integral?

Tags: solution-verification

So this question is very challenging because normally the bases of the exponents are the same. There are too many different bases for me to successfully subtitue in the assumption (when $n=k$)

I was hoping someone out there will have a super smart elegant solution to this!

Base step: test when n = 1 ...

Assume true for $n = 1$
ie . $12^k - 4^k - 3^k +1 = 6M$, where $m$ is an integer

RTP: also true for $n = k+1$
ie.  $12^{k+1} - 4^{k+1} - 3^{k+1} +1 = 6N$ where $N$ is an integer

LHS: $12^{k+1} - 4^{k+1} - 3^{k+1} +1$

$= 12( 4^k + 3^k  - 1 + 6M) - 4^{k}(4) - 3^{k}(3) +1$ (from assumption)

$= 6(12M) + 12(4^k) + 12(3^k) -12 -4^{k}(4) - 3^{k}(3) +1$

Here is where I break down and go around in circles.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what the possibly values of $ 3^n \equiv \pmod{6}$ are?

Comment: Observe that$$12^n-4^n-3^n+1=(3^n-1)(4^n-1)$$

Comment: @CalvinLin I thought someone would do the mod thing. I actually haven't done modular arithmetic yet, so is there another way? There should be a way to prove it using purely algebra

Comment: @user170231 Doesn' that make it worse when you assume $n = k+1$

Comment: Well, $3^n-1$ is always divisible by $2$, since any power of $3$ is odd. So you just need to prove that $3\mid4^n-1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @CalvinLin ok I added my working out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to replace $4^n=12^n-3^n+1-6M$

$\begin{align}12^{n+1}-4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}+1
&=12.12^n-4.4^n-3.3^n+1\\
&=12.12^n-4(12^n-3^n+1-6M)-3.3^n+1\\
&=8.12^n+3^n-3+24M
\end{align}$

$12^n$ and $24M$ are obviously divisible by $6$

Notice $3^n-3=3\times\underbrace{(3^{n-1}-1)}_{\text{even}}$ is also divisible by $6$ so you can finish your induction step.

Answer (score 1):

Work mod 3, and put aside induction for now. Note that  $4 \equiv_3 1$, and so for each integer $n$:

$$4^n \equiv_3 1^n = 1.$$

Thus $12^n -4^n -3^n +1 \equiv_3 (0 -1 -0 -1) = 0$.

So this quantity is divible by 3 for each positive integer $n$.

Lets now get back to mod 6 though. So $12^n -4^n -3^n +1$ is divisible by 3. But it is also even so it is divisible by 6 as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without modular arithmetic? It is after all a mathematical induction question

Comment: I am sorry @user71207 I have no idea how to use induction per se to solve this--or why it would even be called for. Modular arithmetic is used to solve these--and every solution would have to use this implicitly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To prove the claim that $3\mid4^n-1$, notice that

$$4^{k+1}-1=4(4^k-1)+3$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $6 | 12^{n}-4^{n}-3^{n}+1$ for some $n$.

Then $6| 12(12^{n}-4^{n}-3^{n}+1) = 12^{n+1}-12\cdot4^{n}-12\cdot3^{n}+12=$

$12^{n+1}-3\cdot4^{n+1}-4\cdot3^{n+1}+12.$

Since $3^{m} \equiv 3 \pmod 6$, and $4^{m} \equiv 4 \pmod 6$ for every $m$, we have that
$2\cdot4^{n+1} + 3\cdot3^{n+1}-11 \equiv2+3+1\equiv0\pmod 6.$

Hence, $6|(12^{n+1}-3\cdot4^{n+1}-4\cdot3^{n+1}+12)+(2\cdot4^{n+1} + 3\cdot3^{n+1}-11) = 12^{n+1}-4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}+1$.